# SSD Garbage Collection On A None Idle Drive?

Tags: ssd

If I understand correctly, SSD garbage collection runs when the drive is idle. What if it is a PC is on 24 hours with logs writing? By that logic, the drive is never idle and garbage collection will never run, correct?

Comment: Yes, but it is hard to give an SSD really 100% load. It might still have idle times, even though the computer is producing files like crazy, because it is so fast.